# C# Stack want to ask which fruit they want to eat

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, stack

My aim in this program is to Push each fruit the user wants to eat to the stack and Pop the last fruit entered every time they type E means they want to eat now, everytime the user will type E it will show the stack content and it will show a message if the stack is empty already.
The code is not working. How can I add the fruits continuously and check if the stack is empty?

```cs
Stack<string> st = new Stack<string>();    
Console.WriteLine("A: Apple");
Console.WriteLine("O: Orange");
Console.WriteLine("M: Mango");
Console.WriteLine("G: Guava");
Console.WriteLine("E: If you want to eat now the fruit");

do { 
    Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    char fruit = char.Parse(choice);

    if (fruit == 'A'){
        st.Push("Apple");
    }
    else if (fruit == 'O'){
        st.Push("Orange");  
    }
    else if (fruit == 'M'){
        st.Push("Mango");
    }
    else if (fruit == 'G'){
        st.Push("Guava"); 
    }
    else if (fruit == 'E'){
        st.Pop(); 
        foreach (Object obj in st){
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N)");
}
while(!Console.ReadLine().Equals('N'));
```

Comment: Is it working? If not, then what is happening?

Comment: it is not working, it shows this message " Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. "

Comment: At which line, please add the error message as well as the line  it's at in your question.

Comment: _"How can I [...] check if the stack is empty?"_ See [Stack.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack.count?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: BTW `st.Pop();` will throw `InvalidOperationException` if the stack is empty.

Comment: @Codor It will add a value "Apple" to the stack if the user type A, and it did but I want it to be like a loop question but I got stuck when I added the do-while loop. It just ended without letting the user input something and just show the Unhandled Exception message

Comment: Probably not te core of the problem, but `Console.ReadLine().Equals('N')` will always return false, since the types are different, `Console.ReadLine` returns a string, and the single quote, a char, for your comparison to work as intended, you should use double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and answers! another thing I want to ask is how can I display the current content of the stack? like after the user input E it will show the all of the content

Comment: So did my answer solve the issue for you? Were you typing in Ctrl-Z?

Comment: `like after the user input E it will show the all of the content` You already wrote the loop to do that in your code. Is it not working?

Comment: sadly It is not working

Comment: How _specifically_ is it not working? Since it is working for me.

Comment: But I think I got to figure it out on my own. I asked too many questions already. Thanks!

Comment: Well that was a fruitful (pun intended) use of my time. Hint - apply the changes I suggested below, and consider moving the `st.Pop()` _after_ the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Does that mean, I'll _never get to see the stacktrace_ ?? Nooooooooooo

Comment: @mjwills I'll take that in my mind Sir, thank you again.

Answer (score -2):

One possible cause is that `choice` is `null` (which would throw the `ArgumentNullException` exception you are experiencing on the `char.Parse` call). The fact that `Console.ReadLine` can return `null` (if you press Ctrl-Z at the console) is often missed.

This means that:

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
char fruit = char.Parse(choice);
```

should likely instead be:

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
char fruit = char.TryParse(choice, out var result) : result : 'P'; // P meaning invalid input
```

and:

```
while (!Console.ReadLine().Equals('N'));
```

should likely be:

```
while (Console.ReadLine() != "N");
```

Comment: This comment _" It will add a value "Apple" to the stack if the user type A, and it did but I want it to be like a loop question but I got stuck when I added the do-while loop. It just ended without letting the user input something and just show the Unhandled Exception message"_ somehow drags me to believe, that the exception is in the Equals of the while condition rather than in char.Parse ...

Comment: @Fildor That is possible, yes - although the exception would be a different one to the claimed `ArgumentNullException` in that case.

Comment: It really puzzles me. Dying to see the stacktrace ...